# Kali Linux not booting on RPi 3b +

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have flashed Kali Linux on raspberry pi 3b+, but it does not get pass this screen:

[image: Loading]

It just hangs there with a blinking line at the bottom, as if it waits for input. I have no keyboard to test with, but this should not happen and it should boot straight to desktop. Can anyone identify the problem from the image? It is a new install, 64 bit version of Kali for rpi.

Comment: Just to eliminate a weird hardware-related problem: Does raspbian boot properly?

Comment: I actually have never tried raspbian on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the arm image from [cdimage.kali.org/kali-weekly/](http://cdimage.kali.org/kali-weekly/) (Pre-built Version) or use the [build script](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/build-scripts/kali-arm/blob/master/README.md) to create the custom image.

[Kali Linux – Raspberry Pi](https://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi)